# Can one access variable name from inside its defining function in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have a variable, I can print its declared name out as follows in C#:

```
String myVar = "This is a string.";
Console.WriteLine($"This variable is named {(((MemberExpression)((Expression<Func<string>>)(()=>T)).Body).Member.Name)}.");
```

This prints `This variable is named myVar.`

However, I would need this inside the scope of its defining function, i.e.

```
String myVar = f(args);
public String f(args) {
    String name = ...
    //here goes any code necessary to make name = "myVar"
}
```

What code do I need to put inside `f` to recover the variable name? Is this possible at all? I presume it's a bit more complicated than the previous one.

Comment: Are you asking about `nameof(myVar)`?

Comment: So you are asking, if I am a function, can I get the name of the variable to which the result of my completion will be assigned?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output. your comment inside `f` is confusing, since `myVar` is the name of the variable being assigned from the result of `f`, and is not being passed into `f`.

Comment: No `args` is a reference to data (string value), and it does not know what other references there are outside of the function pointing to the same data.

Comment: Your first two lines do not produce the stated output; in fact there's a compile error because `T` is not defined. Please update your code with a working sample.

Comment: Its odd to me that you are using such a complex construction here to get the name of a variable instead of using nameof. Can you say a bit about why you made that choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this possible at all?

No. First, the value returned by a method need not be assigned to a variable at all. Second, even if it is assigned to a variable, not all variables have names. Therefore there is no way to know the name of the variable that the value of a function call will be assigned to.

The best practice is to always design functions so that they compute values independently of the details of the caller.

(It *is* possible to get the source code location of the caller from the callee, but that feature should be limited to debugging and diagnostic purposes.)

This sounds very much like an "XY" question. That is, you have some real problem, you have come up with a wrong solution to that problem, and now you are asking a question about the wrong solution. What's the real problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: Hi Eric, why do you say that it is not possible at all ? I'm no expert. So I would like to know your thoughts please

Comment: Because the method call need not be assigned to a variable, and even if it is, the variable might not have a name. Since the variable name might not exist there cannot be a reliable way to obtain the variable name.

Comment: "variable name might not exist" does it refer to a scenario where you are pasing string value to `GetIdentifier ("Hello")` ? In my example

Comment: The real problem is that I use a pre-exising system that internally uses Strings to refer to objects, while in my code I want to use variables (to have all the IDE benefits like seeing if the variable exists, highlight where else it is used, etc.). 
Unfortunately this makes my screen filled with hundreds of oneliners `var myVar = myFunction(args,"myVar",moreArgs);`. I will need the string inside myFunction so I can't skip that argument, I need a variable with the same name in my code to get the IDE benefits, but that now means I need to write every name twice (and edit twice if changes, etc.)

Comment: @Clint: Consider: `M();` the return is discarded, so there is no variable to assign to. Consider: `N(M());` -- the variable assigned to is a formal parameter of `N()`.  Consider `P(params object[] x)` and `P(M())`. The variable assigned to is `x[0]` -- what is the *name* of `x[0]`?  Consider `A` returns an array and `X` returns an index; `A()[X()]=M();`  What is the name of the variable assigned to? How about `*((int*)12345678) = M();` in unsafe code; what is the name of the variable?

Comment: @Clint: Suppose `M` returns a sequence; what is the name of the variable assigned to in `foreach(var x in M())`? It is not `x`; `x` is assigned the *members* of the sequence, not the sequence. What is the name of the variable assigned in `return M();`?  What about `var s = from x in M() where x > 10 select x.ToString();` `s` is a completely different sequence than that returned by `M()` so that's not it. What about `if (M().Count() > 10)`, what's the name of the variable assigned to there?  **There are many dozens of ways that a call is never assigned to a variable**.

Comment: @Peter: I see what you're getting at. It sounds like the fundamental problem is that you have a system that uses strings as references in a language that has object reference as a built-in type. Can you modify that system to refer to object by reference rather than this indirection through strings?

Comment: @EricLippert, yes thanks for clarifying and yes there are dozens of ways where call is not assigned to a variable, and I agree, the solution is not applicable in cases where there is no variable, but to answer OPs question isn't it possible to retrieve a `variable` that is passed to a function, to be specific to the question that was asked. **What is the point in doing so, the reasons for complex construct  that led to this design is a different topic**

Comment: @EricLippert I cannot change the internal system for various reasons. I guess I will just live with typing everything twice then.

Answer (score -9):

`nameof` exists, lets use that instead.

```
String myVar = "This is a string.";
Console.WriteLine($"This variable is named {nameof(myVar)}.");
```

So your next bit, we have to make some changes. I'm assuming since you're passing `args` that this is being called in your `Main` method. We need to make `myVar` a class level variable.

```
static String myVar;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      myVar = f(args);
}

public static String f(string[] args) {
    String name = nameof(myVar);
    // Whatever else you're doing
}
```

This is a bit hacky, and relies on you only ever assigning the result of this function to a specific variable which exists outside of the function, and this is certainly against OOP principles and is a definite anti-pattern. With more information about your use case we could probably guide you to a better solution.